# Dropdown to populate from another google sheet range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In FileA - Sheet1, cell A2 I have a dropdown which I need to populate with a range from FileB - Sheet1 A2:A100.

In FileA I am able to import the range and list them, however I need that range to be in the Data Validation for cell A2.

How can I get this to populate in the Data Validation Settings:
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/111111111111", "Sheet1!A2:A100")

Answer (score 1):

After searching further, I had to import the range in another sheet then pull front a range that is referencing. I could not pull directly.